# Alembic. ModuleNotFoundError in env.py

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following project structure

```
 --some db:
        --some db:
            --alchemy:
                -- __init__.py
            --alembic:
                -- versions
                -- env.py
                -- README.py
                -- script.py
            --migrations:
                -- __init__.py
            --models:
                -- model_1
                -- model_2
                -- __init__.py
```

I try to autogenerate migrations by alembic.

I have `Base` in `__init__.py` in models folder

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr


metadata = sa.MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
```

And import this is env.py

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from models import Base

config = context.config
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

So, when I import Base from models in env.py in alembic directory and try to generate automigration I have some error like

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that when `env.py` is executed, `models` is not in your `PYTHONPATH`, so it can't be imported.

With the project structure you've outlined, it might be a little hard to address; the easiest solution might be to modify your `PYTHONPATH` inside `env.py` like this:

```py
import sys

sys.path = ['', '..'] + sys.path[1:]

from models import Base
```

This will add the parent directory of `alembic/` to your `PYTHONPATH` so that it can find the `models` module.

Alternatively, you add the directory containing your modules to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in your shell:

```sh
$ export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/some db/some db':$PYTHONPATH
```

This solution is a little more brittle because you have to remember to do this each session and it will be different for each machine you intend to run Alembic on.

When I ran into this issue, the SQLAlchemy developer [suggested](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/625) that if I was using `pip` and virtual environments, I could install my project in editable mode so that it's in the system `PYTHONPATH` and Alembic would be able to find it from anywhere. More details are available in the [Python packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/). For this, you'd need a `setup.py` for your project and you may want to change your project structure so that there's a top-level module containing things like `models` and `alchemy`. For example:

```
myproj/
    setup.py
    alembic/
        env.py
        migrations/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        alchemy/
            __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py
```

If this is set up correctly, you can

```sh
$ pip install -e .
```

from inside the `myproj/` directory. Then in `env.py` you would then import `Base` like this:

```py
from myapp.models import Base
```

Comment: I don't use Win, but the Windows version should be `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\your\path\`

Answer (score 25):

Now there is a beautiful way: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/commit/d6b0c1af3df98b50c6ec52781aa411592c4e0c32

"...the default "alembic.ini" file includes a directive `prepend_sys_path = .` so that the local path is also in `sys.path`.

Comment: This should be the top answer, it was only introduced in Alembic 1.5.5 (release date February 20, 2021). Tailored to the OPs issue, the solution would be to change the key to `prepend_sys_path = ..` in `alembic.ini`

Comment: yes this wors and is a lot cleaner imo

Answer (score 10):

When a module is loaded from a file in Python, `__file__` is set to its path. You can then use that with other functions to find the directory that the file is located in.

Add the following line in alembic/env.py file to resolve the ModuleNotFoundError

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution for Linux, which I find very easy.
Run the cmd as:

```
PYTHONPATH={your python path} {your alembic cmd}
```

Answer (score 2):

I run `alembic` as a python module, for example:

```
 python3 -m alembic.config upgrade head
```

Comment: For me this is the best answer ✅

Answer (score 1):

I second @Abhishek Dhotre 's anwer since this approach is more universal to all sorts of project structures a developer might have, in my case when I run `uvicorn main:app --reload` I got `No module named app`.

I solved it by including `sys.path.append(path_to_app)` in **env.py**, where path_to_app is relative to the location of **env.py** as follows:

**env.py**

```py
import sys
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../app')
sys.path.append(APP_DIR)
```